# How to add meta box for current post format?

Tags: metabox, post-formats

I wanted to add meta box with current post format like when i select video post format then there will be appear video url input post just under the post editor. How to do that? any help

Comment: What's the 'current' post format?

Comment: like when i select video post format, then there will be appear video url meta box down the editor box

Answer (score 1):

If you want it just for the native `post` post type, then put this in your functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
}
```

The Post Format meta box will now appear down the side of your screen on the post creating/editing page.

Full list of available post formats to pass into the `add_theme_support` function - https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: I wanted to add meta box with current post format like when i select video post format then there will be appear video url input post just under the post editor

Comment: Oh ok. This is going to require JS/AJAX. I suggest first installing the Advanced Custom Fields plugin - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com, and if you don't want to use a third-party plugin, then look at it's code to get a head start.